# Помогите доработать сканер файлов

Tags: c#, рекурсия

В общем нашел на ютюбе видеоурок как сделать простейший сканер по маске. Все бы хорошо,НО прога не ходит по вложенным папкам относительно выбранной папки для проверки. Почитал на форумах и узнал,что тут может помочь рекурсивный поиск. Как его реализовать исходя из кода ниже, я не представляю. Может у кого есть исходники или просто кто-то знает, как это реализовать, буду очень рад.
Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
private int objects = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Выбор отдельной паки//
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        label1.Text = "Путь сканирования: " + folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        objects = 0;
        label2.Text = "Обнаружено объектов: " + objects.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Поиск//
    {
        string[] search = Directory.GetFiles(@folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*");
        progressBar1.Maximum = search.Length;
        foreach (string item in search)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(item);
                string read = stream.ReadToEnd();
                string[] object = File.ReadAllLines("/file.txt");//маска//

                foreach (string st in object)
                {

                    if (Regex.IsMatch(read, st))
                    {
                        objects += 1;
                        label2.Text = "Обнаружено объектов: " + objects.ToString();
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
                    }

                    progressBar1.Increment(1);
                }

                stream.Dispose();
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                string read = item;
                string[] object = File.ReadAllLines("/file.txt");//маска//
                foreach (string st in object)
                {

                    if (Regex.IsMatch(read, st))
                    {

                        objects += 1;
                        label2.Text = "Обнаружено объектов: " + objects.ToString();
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);

                    }

                    progressBar1.Increment(1);

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Что Вы в catch сделать пытаетесь?

Рекурсию как таковую проходили? Вызов функцией самой себя. Как минимум, для начала, надо бы вытащить функцию поиска по директории в отдельный метод.

Comment: ... а также попробовать излечиться от известной болезни всех новичков — имплементации всей программной логики в OnClick.